# OpenCv: Connect edges to make rectangle

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am using **opencv** to detect receipt:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.filters import threshold_local
from PIL import Image
import sys    

file_name = "test.jpg"
image = cv2.imread(file_name)
# Downscale image as finding receipt contour is more efficient on a small image
resize_ratio = 500 / image.shape[0]
original = image.copy()
image = opencv_resize(image, resize_ratio)

# Convert to grayscale for further processing
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Get rid of noise with Gaussian Blur filter
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)

# Detect white regions
rectKernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (9, 9))
dilated = cv2.dilate(blurred, rectKernel)

# Detect edge
edged = cv2.Canny(dilated, 40, 200, apertureSize=3)

# Detect all contours in Canny-edged image
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
image_with_contours = cv2.drawContours(image.copy(), contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)

# Create hull to have good shape rectangle
    # Find the convex hull object for each contour
hull_list = []
for i in range(len(contours)):
        hull = cv2.convexHull(contours[i])
        hull_list.append(hull)

image_with_hull = cv2.drawContours(image.copy(), hull_list, -1, (0,255,0), 3)

# Get 10 largest contours
#largest_contours = sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:10]
largest_contours = sorted(hull_list, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:10]
image_with_largest_contours = cv2.drawContours(image.copy(), largest_contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
```

[image]

I am detecting **image contours** and once I have the contours I would like to make it a rectangle to make sure I capture a complete receipt. I am using convex hull for making the rectangle, but the problem is convex hull not follow straight lines (I mean along with border of the receipt, like in 90-degree angle) instead it just connects the points where it stopped which is not correct. Is it possible to make a rectangle with 4 points to capture a complete receipt? something like this:

[image]

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just threshold on the white of the original receipt (not the grayscale version) using cv2.inRange(). Use morphology to clean up. Then get contours and then the rotated rectangle using cv2.minAreaRect().

Comment: @fmw42 Thanks for the hint. Will try that and let you know. But one thing is that, that receipt in bluish color not white.

Comment: Use cv2.inRange() on the bluish white color.

Comment: cv2.inRange isn't working as receipt color changes because of light intensity. Also, some scripts are totally white.

Comment: If the receipts have good contrast against the background, then you can widen the range to cover most receipt recoloring due to light changes.  Or you can convert to HSV and and get values that have high brightness and low saturation, since your white receipt has little color (assuming the background is not similarly colored).

Comment: @fmw42 thanks, will try that. But cannot guarantee of having always a good contrast of receipt with the background.

Comment: If the contrast is not good with the background, white receipt on white background, no simple image processing technique will work. You may need to look into AI/Deep learning and training a lot of receipts on different backgrounds.